# How can a memory space allocated by mmap() protected from getting allocated by 'new' calls?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm allocating space at a specific address using

`mmap(...,PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED,...)`

But if I call something like `new char[large_number]` that array is created overlapping the previously allocated memory segment. So my question is what should I do to protect the memory segment I've tried to allocate earlier.

EDIT:
For the following code,

```
char* base_address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(long));
int page_size = getpagesize();
size_t length = page_size;
char* selected_address = (char*)base_address + (page_size - ((long)base_address % page_size));

char* allocated_address = (char*) mmap(selected_address, page_size * 4, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ
    ,  MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0);

int* a = new int[page_size / 4];
// mprotect(allocated_address, page_size * 4, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
int* b = new (allocated_address) int[page_size / 2];
int* c = new (allocated_address + page_size / 2 ) int[page_size/2];

int* d = (int*)malloc(page_size);

cout << "base_address:" << (int*)base_address << " selected_address:" << (int*)selected_address << " allocated_address:" << (int*)allocated_address << endl;
cout << "a=" << a << " end=" << &a[page_size/4 - 1] << endl;
cout << "b=" << b << " end=" << &b[page_size/2 - 1] << endl;
cout << "c=" << c << " end=" << &c[page_size/2 - 1] << endl;
cout << "d=" << d << " end=" << &d[page_size - 1] << endl;
```

I'm getting

```
base_address:0x603010 selected_address:0x604000 allocated_address:0x604000
a=0x603030 end=0x60402c
b=0x604000 end=0x605ffc
c=0x604800 end=0x6067fc
d=0x604040 end=0x60803c
```

Shouldn't the a and d segments allocated outside of the mmap allocated space?

Comment: Can you give an example? What you described shouldn't happen.

Comment: If your implementation's memory allocation code is letting you do that with `MAP_FIXED`, then it's badly broken (and insecure, as it implies someone able to provide e.g. a variable length string could cause a memory allocation that overwrote the shared memory with arbitrary content, potentially affecting other processes too).  Which OS is this?  If you just want a quick fix, ditch `MAP_FIXED` if possible.

Comment: This is the first time I'm using mmap. Therefore probably my code would have some fault. thanks.

Comment: I wanted the memory to allocate at a specific location rather than a random location that's why I've used MAP_FIXED.

Comment: @SankaD See my answer as to why you can't use `MAP_FIXED` and expect this to work.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `mmap` in the first place?? It looks like you don't need it. Why not just use `new`? And tell us which OS you are using (so edit your question).

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to find a way to allocate memory at a location of my choosing rather than a location provided by the allocator. And I'm using Linux 3.0.74-0.6.10-default kernel. It was a problem of me trying to allocate a page already allocated to the glibc rather than an OS related issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page of mmap on my system (OS X)

> If MAP_FIXED is specified in flags, the system will try to place the mapping at the specified address, possibly removing a mapping that already exists at that location.

you are forcing `mmap()` to map at the first page above an address handed to you by `malloc()`.  It is likely that `new` calls `malloc()` to get memory blocks and it is likely that the memory allocator thinks it owns the page that you are trying to map to.  You don't tell the allocator that it can't use that page, so it goes ahead and does it.

**Do not specify `MAP_FIXED`**. Just use the address it gives back to you without `MAP_FIXED` specified.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem that way. I specifically set a value for the base_address using malloc() to check whether this type of thing is possible. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> `mmap(...,PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED,...)`

A memory mapping can only be either `MAP_SHARED` or `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, but not both.

> But if I call something like `new char[large_number]` that array is created overlapping the previously allocated memory segment.

This is not possible. You ignore the return value of `mmap` call, the call most likely fails.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying with MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED. Copied the wrong version to the question. I've edited the code. And the return value is the address I'm using as the allocated address. And the errno = 0

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation platform likely grows the heap implicitly, by keeping track of the highest page address used by the heap, then simply increasing it when needed. The first access to a previously unused page generates a page fault, and the O/S then automatically increases the process's virtual memory address space, starting at the faulted address.

On Linux, see the sbrk(2) man page for a more complete description of this process.

So what happened here, is that you explicitly requested something mmap()ed to an address exactly where the C library will be using next, for allocated memory. And the C library happily proceeded to increase the data segment, intruding on your mmap-ed space.

This is a simple case of "Doctor, it hurts when I wave my arm like this."; "Well, don't do wave your arm like that."

The mmap() man page on Linux offers this caution about the first parameter to mmap():

> If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the address at which to create
>   the mapping; this is the most portable method of creating  a  new  map‐ping.

An NULL address results in the kernel mapping your new memory segment at an address that's nowhere near anything else, and nowhere near the process's data segment, and the two won't interfere with each other.

If, as in your case, you're explicitly mmap()ing a specific address in your virtual address space, the onus is on you to avoid running into trouble, and knowing exactly what's going on within your process, including what the C library is doing.

And I should also note that in order to calculate the new mmaped address, you're calculating a pointer address that's past the end of a currently allocated array.

This is, strictly, undefined behavior. All bets are off, at this point, as far as strict C/C++ compliance goes, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You are `mmap`-ing an address given by `new` or `malloc`. You should not do that (and it often should fail with `MAP_FIXED`  since an address returned by `new` or `malloc` is *rarely* page-aligned).

I guess that you are using Linux. So code:

```
char* allocated_address
    = (char*) mmap(NULL, page_size * 4, 
                   PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ,
                   MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
if (allocated_address == MMAP_FAILED)
     { perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };

int* b = new ((void*)allocated_address) int[page_size / 2];
int* c = new ((void*)(allocated_address + (page_size / 2)*sizeof(int)))
            int[page_size/2];
```

Notice that the byte size of an array `int[page_size/2]` is `sizeof(int)*(page_size/2)`. On my system (Linux/x86-64/Debian/Sid) `sizeof(int)` is 4, and `page_size` is 4096.

Read carefully [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) the result of `mmap` (*without* `MAP_FIXED`, which you should almost never use, except when mapping *again* a previously mmaped address segment) is often non-reproducible from one run to the next.

BTW, when your program is running as pid 1234, run `cat /proc/1234/maps` in a separate terminal (from *inside* your program you could even read sequentially line by line and parse `/proc/self/maps`); it will show you the address space of process 1234. Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)